# Getting EPG info from DVB-T

Tags: epg

I'm interested in grabbing the EPG data from DVB-T streams. Does anyone know of any C libraries or an alternative means of getting the data?

Comment: This can be another good alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35651812/2119685

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tv_grab_dvb can do this. See the [subversion repository](http://www.darkskiez.co.uk/svn/tv_grab_dvb/trunk/) for sources.

tv_grab_dvb is made to work with the stream grabbed from the DVB-T card using [dvbtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvbtools/) on Linux, but it may be portable to other platforms - I think it just works with the raw data from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

...a new answer to an old question:

I wrote a utility called `dvbtee` that can be used as a c++ library, a cross-platform command line utility, or a node.js module.

(despite it being a c++ library, one could still link to it from c code)

The command line utility will parse your streams and output the EPG, depending on the arguments you specify, it can generate plain text or a JSON block of data.

[dvbtee: a digital television streamer / parser / service information aggregator supporting various interfaces including telnet CLI & http control](http://mkrufky.github.io/libdvbtee)

The node.js module will emit events containing the PSIP table data (along with EPG info)

[node-dvbtee: MPEG2 transport stream parser for Node.js with support for television broadcast PSIP tables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dvbtee)

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question.

Comment: Rather the other one. The other question is the duplicate.

Comment: actually, i'm not sure that deleting my answer is the best idea in this case.   The other question asks for something more general, while this question specifically asks for a C library.   My answer satisfies both questions, which are not duplicates of each other.

Comment: (for the record, the other question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362103/how-to-extract-epg-from-dvb-t-live-tv-stream-udp-with-ffmpeg/42530575 )