# how to extract EPG from dvb-t (live tv stream - udp) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, dvb, epg

I want to extract EPG from dvb-t (live tv stream - udp) with ffmpeg. 
I have a dvb-t device and receiving streams with udp.

Comment: whats your streamer?do you get dvb signal with ffmpeg directly? whats your client that yu want see epg on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting EPG info from DVB-T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249/getting-epg-info-from-dvb-t)

Answer (score 2):

I have an dvb-t udp .ts stream generated with mumudvb and I can extract the EPG guide info in XMLTV format with epgrab - https://github.com/hiroshiyui/epgrab

```
git clone https://github.com/hiroshiyui/epgrab.git
cd epgrab/
cmake .
make
# Point epgrab to your dvb adapter
./epgrab -i /dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0 > out.xml
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it does, i actually have mumudvb streaming, while ffmpeg extracts subtitles and epgraber gets the guide. all these three programs run from only one tv tuner

Comment: do you know how we extract epg from devlast stream?

Comment: don't know about a stream. If it's a Transport Stream I'm guessing it will have the EPG guide attached to it. I can see this EPG guide from VLC for example from a TS, but not sure how to extract it. My answer was for extracting it from a DVB card

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility called `dvbtee` that can be used as a c++ library, a cross-platform command line utility, or a node.js module.

The command line utility will parse your streams and output the EPG, depending on the arguments you specify, it can generate plain text or a JSON block of data.

[dvbtee: a digital television streamer / parser / service information aggregator supporting various interfaces including telnet CLI & http control](http://mkrufky.github.io/libdvbtee)

The node.js module will emit events containing the PSIP table data (along with EPG info)

[node-dvbtee: MPEG2 transport stream parser for Node.js with support for television broadcast PSIP tables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dvbtee)